# Comma before indefinite pronoun

Tags: pronouns, commas, indefinite-pronouns

While I would surround a noun or pronoun with commas, should I do the same for indefinite pronouns? For example:

> Have a good weekend, all.
>
> I'm sorry, everybody, I can't do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vocatives are normally set off with commas, James.

Comment: Thanks, @tchrist, for clearing up the fact that 'all' is also a vocative.